# angularJs multiple orderBy

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

I am using the orderBy functionality in AngularJs. My requirement would be sort the surname by ascending and the name column by descending order. I have can make use of '+' and '-' to resolve the same. 
But I want some dynamic mechanism to handle this. Is there anyway I can utilise the angularjs to solve my issue or should I go forward and write my own customised sort functionality?

```
    <tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts | orderBy:['surname','name']:true">
```

As I said earlier below code will fix this issue,

```
    <tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts | orderBy:['-surname','+name']">
```

But here surname property will change all the time and its asc/dec dynamically when the table is sorted.

```
    <tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts | orderBy:['+salary','+name']">
    <tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts | orderBy:['-age','+name']">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use values in $scope to change the order by of clause of ng-repeat.
Use the orderOptions scope variable in ng-repeat for orderBy filter.

```
 <tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts | orderBy:orderOptions">
```

set orderOptions in controller scope.

```
$scope.orderOptions = ['+salary','+name']
```

You can update the oderOptions when ever you required using functions. The sort order of the table will updated accordingly.

```
$scope.orderOptions = ['-age','+name']
```

Comment: Ok.. I had something similar in the mind to use scope variables and handle in controller.. Will try that